# redirect to another page if (text area (input) === "something") when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This is the way I approached it. Please help:

Search

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var criteria = document.getElementById("search").val().toLowerCase();

    if (criteria == "crosshatching") {
        document.getElementById("searchBtn").onclick = function() {
            window.location.href = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=117AN3MQuVs";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `val` is jQuery. You’re looking for `value`.

Answer (score 1):

There was no scope for the variable `criteria` inside the function. 
Also `.val()` is for jQuery, instead use Javascript's `.value`.
I've modified your code.
Please check the working code below :

```js
  document.getElementById("searchBtn").onclick = function() {
    var criteria = document.getElementById("search").value.toLowerCase();

    if (criteria == "crosshatching") {
      alert("Matching");
      window.location.href = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=117AN3MQuVs";
    } else {
      alert("NOT Matching");
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="search" id="search"></textarea>
<button id="searchBtn">Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the value of your input *inside* the event handler. In addition, as pointed out in the comments, use `value` instead of `val()`.

```js
document.getElementById('searchBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var criteria = document.getElementById('search').value.toLowerCase();
    if (criteria === "crosshatching") {
        console.log('You would be redirected here!')
        location.href = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=117AN3MQuVs'
    } else {
        console.log('No redirect. You wrote: ' + criteria)
    }
})
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text"/>
<button id="searchBtn">Search</button>
```